# WordPress responsive theme: 'Login' not responsive while 'Register' and 'Lost Password' are

Tags: iphone, wordpress, mobile, responsive-design, themes

I'm using the excellent WordPress Bones theme, and I'm having an issue with my WP Login screen.

If you view the Login screen on a mobile device, the viewport ***is not*** responsive and does not conform to the screen size. But if you view the 'Register' or 'Lost Password' screens, the viewport ***is*** responsive and does conform to the screen size.

You can view the login screen [here](https://www.dcturano.com/entrance). Any idea as to why the Login screen isn't responsive?

Comment: Its is responsive to me in Android. Did you fix it already?

Comment: Haven't touched it yet. Perhaps it's just iOS? It's happening on both an iPad and iPhone.

Comment: I don't any iOS device, and since your link is https I can't  test it in any emulator online which could give me a glimpse of whats going on.

Comment: I look at your source code and you don't have meta  viewport tag, try adding this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`